# XAMPP Subdomain with Joomla Site

Tags: php, apache, joomla, subdomain, virtualhost

I'm using XAMPP v3.2.4 and I don't know if this makes any difference but Joomla 3.9.14

In my local environment I access my Joomla site by visiting `localhost/mysite`. I now want to have a sub domain `localhost/apps.mysite`.

I've created a folder called `apps` and placed this in my Joomla root directory, which is `C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\apps`. This folder contains a single `index.html` file.

I've made the following changes;

In my Windows `hosts` file I added the following line;

```
127.0.0.1           localhost/apps.mysite
```

In my `httpd-vhosts.conf` file I added;

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80
<virtualhost *:80="">
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite/apps"
    ServerName localhost/apps.mysite
    ServerAlias www.apps.mysite.localhost.com
</virtualhost>
```

I haven't made any other changes to config files. I've restarted Apache a few times, no change.

When I visit the URL `http://localhost/apps.mysite` I see the following error;

> Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. If
>   you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404 localhost Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.3.9

What do I need to change in order to access my subdomain at `http://localhost/apps.mysite`

Comment: Unlikely your actual problem but as of Apache 2.4 the `NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80` is not necessary and generates at least a warning as I remember

Comment: `<virtualhost *:80="">` I dont think the `=""` should be there

Comment: Yea, the VH is nowhere near right. Have you read http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html

Comment: I would suggest 1. Create a VH for your main site. then 2. create a sub domain of that domain.  Basically dont use `localhost` in the name at all

Comment: `localhost/apps.mysite` is not a proper subdomain - what are you really looking for? A subdomain could be `apps.mysite` or `apps.localhost`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** host file does not handle folders, just map IP addresses to hostname.

Host file should be

```
127.0.0.1 localhost apps.mysite
```

or

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 apps.mysite
```

I prefer the second method because I can comment the line..

**Second** Your virtual host ***ServerName localhost/apps.mysite*** does not work with sub folders.

Valid Servername values can be: domain.com, example.com, site1.example.com, user.site1.example.com and son on.

A virtual host example to map the apps.mysite should be:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName apps.mysite
  ServerAlias  www.apps.mysite
  ## Vhost Document Root
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite/apps"
</VirtualHost>
```

This is a minimal example, no logs defined or directory specific rules. With this configuration you will be able to reach your site by using http://apps.mysite only on your computer because the host file is resolving the "apps.mysite" to your localhost (127.0.0.1).

> What do I need to change in order to access my subdomain at http://localhost/apps.mysite

http://localhost/apps.mysite is not a sub-domain is a domain localhost with a folder apps.mysite, a valid subdomain is subDomain.domain.com.

**.com** is a top level domain
**domain.com** is a domain name
**subDomain.domain.com** is a subdomain of domain.com

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Start by creating a VirtualHost for localhost in case you want to use that for a bit of fiddling

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
  <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs"/>
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

## then add main site
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mysite.local
  ServerAlias www.mysite.local
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite/"
  <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite/"/>
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

## then add the sub domain
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName aps.mysite.local
  ServerAlias www.aps.mysite.local
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/mysiteapps/"
  <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/mysiteapps/"/>
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You will need to add these 2 sites to your `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file like this

```
127.0.0.1 mysite.local aps.mysite.local
::1 mysite.local aps.mysite.local
```

For the change to the HOSTS file you will either need to reboot or refresh the DNS Cache like this from a command window

```
>ipconfig /flushdns
```

Comment: Its probably related to what is already in `httpd-vhosts.conf` before the code I gave you. Can you show all that file please. I am not familiar with XAMPP base files, I am a WAMPServer user myself

Comment: Ok so DONT repeat the first VH I gave you for localhost. That one already exists

Comment: Did you put these into the httpd.conf file as well?